# Win32 API in VC++ platform

Tags: winapi

Can anyone help me in getting the video training for Win32(Windows programming) in VC++ platform ...

Comment: what do you mean by video training?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb496952.aspx